# WSO2 3.2.0 Analytic is empty

Tags: wso2, analytics, wso2-api-manager

I download API Manager 3.2.0 and then download Analytic 3.2.0 and goto deployment.toml and enable analytic. then Publish an api and call from devportal but Dashborad is empty . and analytic dont work.
and I don't have any errors in command prompt.

[image]

Comment: what setup did you follow as in the docs? quick setup or standard setup?  https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/learn/analytics/configuring-apim-analytics/#configuring-apim-analytics

Comment: No command line errors in any of the 3 servers? Do you see any errors in browser console or netwok tab?

Comment: I don't have any error.I use database h2 and just do 5 step of this document.I just enable analytic in deployment.toml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check path of apim_database in section "[database.apim_db]" in this file *C:\Program Files\WSO2\API Manager\3.2.0\repository\conf\deployment.toml*  and in section "wso2.datasources:" , name AM_DB in this *C:\Program Files\WSO2\API Manager\wso2am-analytics-3.2.0\conf\dashboard\deployment.yaml*

Both must have same configuration